# Fullcalendar doesn't allow to set timezones for the Scheduler

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

There is an issue with setting time zone for the Scheduler.
We can set the time zone only local PC time('local') or UTC('UTC'), however it doesn't allow to set another time zone like 'Canada/Atlantic' or 'Europe/Athens'.
working:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            timezone: "local",
            ....
})
```

no working:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            timezone: "Canada/Atlantic",
            ....
})
```

Please help how to set any time zone for the Scheduler calendar.